# Woocommerce: remove 'visit site' or 'visit store'

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce adds 'visit store' in the admin bar in Wordpress whenever I activate it. This has the consequence that I have both a 'visit site' and a 'visit store' there.

However, I don't really see what the benefit is of this (please tell me if there is any) - so I want to get rid of either that or the 'visit site' link. How can I do that?

(My question is very similar to that of the poster here but I don't have access to that forum - maybe someone else does? http://www.kadencethemes.com/support-forums/topic/woocommerce-remove-visit-store/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use this.

```
function remove_admin_bar_links() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('view-site');        // Remove the view site link
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('site-name');        // Remove the site name menu
}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'remove_admin_bar_links' );
```

Comment: Thank you! Where do I add this i.e. to what file?

Comment: in your childtheme functions.php.

Comment: Thanks, that works! The only thing is that if I visit the old link where 'view site' leads to, it still exists. How can I delete it? (What I'm trying to say is that even though this did remove it from the admin bar, it didn't delete the page it links to).

Comment: Can you give the link, so that I can test the same thing in my localhost and if you think this is the solution mark it as solution.

Comment: For now I have just changed the code for visit-store .

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. Removing 'view site' like you initially had is actually the best option for me since I want to build a store. The link where I can then still find mysite is: http://localhost/mysite/ (mysite is the website name). Preferably I would want to delete that page, since it has no function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91201/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-dreamer).

Answer (score 2):

```
function remove_admin_bar_links() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('view-site');  // Remove the view site link
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('view-store'); // Remove the view store link
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('site-name');  // Remove the site name menu
}    
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'remove_admin_bar_links' );
```